# Reference coordinate system changes between OpenCV, OpenGL and Android Sensor

Tags: opengl-es, opencv, rotation, android-sensors, coordinate-transformation

I am working with **OpenCV**, **Android** and **OpenGL** for an Augmented Reality project. As far as I know the coordintate system in OpenGL is

[image]

The OpenCV coordinate system is:

[image]

When combining these devices with android sensors how can I do the coordinate system conversions and [R|t] matrix conversion? Is there a good tutorial or documentation were all of this conffusing stuff is explained?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look at the picture, then you see, that the both coordinate systems have the same handednes, but the OpenCV one is rotated by pi around the x axis. This can be represented by the following rotation matrix:

```
 1  0  0
 0 -1  0
 0  0 -1
```

Comment: Yes, for changing between openCV and OpenGL an inversion about y and z axis is needed. The biggest problem comes with android sensors...

Comment: It is *not* a rotation. The coordinate system (y-axis) is flipped at the x-axis. The z-axis is unaffected.

Comment: @Stefan: Look again: In the pictures OP pasted into his answer the Z axis has been flipped, too. According to those pictures (OpenGL Z axis comes out of the screen, OpenCV Z axis goes into the screen) it's a rotation by 180° along the X axis.