# Understanding the output of solvepnp?

Tags: ios, opencv, rotational-matrices, euler-angles

I am have been using `solvepnp()` for the calculation of the rotation and translation matrix. But the euler angles calculated from the obtained rotation matrix gave very erratic values. Trying to find the problem, I had a set of 2D projection points for my marker and kept the other parameters of `solvepnp()` constant.
Eg values:

**2D points**
`[219.67473, 242.78395;`
 `363.4151, 238.61298;` 
`503.04855, 234.56117;`
 `501.70917, 628.16742;` 
`500.58069, 959.78564;` 
`383.1756, 972.02679;`
 `262.8746, 984.56982;` 
`243.17044, 646.22925]`

The  euler angle **theta(x)** calculated from the output rotation matrix of solvepnp() was **-26.4877**

Next, I incremented only the x value of the first point(i.e 219.67473) by 0.1 to check the variation of the theta(x) euler angle (keeping the remaining points  and the other parameters constant)  and ran the solvepnp() again .For that very small change,I had values which were decreasing from -19 degree, -18 degree (for x coord = 223.074) then suddenly jump to 27 degree for a while (for x coord = 223.174 to 226.974) then come down to 1.3 degree (for x coord = 227.074).

I cannot understand this behaviour at all.Could somebody please explain? 
My euler angle calculation from the rotation matrix uses [this procedure](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Rodrigues()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=solvepnp#void%20Rodrigues%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20OutputArray%20jacobian%29) for conversion between rotation matrix and rotation vector to make sure everything is clean and right. Non RANSAC version can be very sensitive to outliers that create  a huge error in the parameters and thus bias a solution. Using [RANSAC version](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=solvepnpran#cv2.solvePnPRansac) of solvePnP may make it more stable to outliers. For example, adding too much to one of the points coordinates will eventually make it an outlier and it won’t influence a solution after that.

If everything fails, write a series unit tests: create an artificial set of points in 3D (possibly non planar), apply a simple translation first, in second variant apply rotation only, and in a third test apply both. Project using your camera matrix and then plug in your  2D, 3D points and projection matrix into your code to find the pose. If the result deviates from the inverse of the translations and rotations your applied to the points look for the bug in feeding parameters to PnP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the coordinate systems are different.OpenCV uses [right-hand coordinate-system Y-pointing downwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081900/reference-coordinate-system-changes-between-opencv-opengl-and-android-sensor). At nghiaho.com it says the calculations are based on [this](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node102.html) and if you look at the axis they don't seem to match. I guess you are using [Rodrigues](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues) for matrix computation? Try comparing rotation vectors as well.